# Centering divs using Pure.css

Tags: html

I'm using [Pure.css](http://purecss.io), and this is the code I have.

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-3-5">

        <h3 class="content-subhead">Title</h3>

        <p>
            Sample Text
        </p>
        <a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
```

I want this div to be centered when in small screen, so I tried `is-center`, but it centers everything regardless of screen size. I tried reading the guides but I couldn't find any info.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want CSS some behaviour to happen only for a certain screen size, your best bet is look at CSS Media Queries.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Pure.css is most likely using media queries behind the scene. If you couldn't find the right class for this behaviour in pure.css's docs, then you're probably going to need to make your own class that does this.

Here are some steps to get you started:
1. Learn css Media Queries
2. Find the is-center class CSS in the source code of Pure.css module
3. find the correct pixel cut-off for small screen by looking at the media queries in pure.css
4. apply the appropriate media query to the is-center class to create your new class
5. give this class an appropriate name, e.g. is-center-sm

Comment: Thank you! I thought there would be a better way to do it but I guess not!